# Removing record of relationship OneToMany bidirectional?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm looking for how to I can remove a register of relationship OneToMany/ManyToOne.
The problem is when I do EntityManager.remove(), all records are removed and I want that only child(DiasTurma) is removed and not your parent(Turma).

here how I'm trying

```
// parent
@Entity
public class Turma implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull @Column(unique = true)
    private String turmaNome;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "turma", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DiasTurma> diasTurma = new ArrayList<DiasTurma>();
    //gets/sets


//child
@Entity
public class DiasTurma implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String horaInicio;
    private String horaFim;
    private String diaSemana;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_turma")
    private Turma turma;
    //gets/sets


// DAO
/** remove DiasTurma of Turma */
public void removeDiasTurma(){
        DiasTurma dias = (DiasTurma)em.find(DiasTurma.class, 3);
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(dias);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
```

The method `removeDiasTurma()` execute a remove, but all records including record of Turma is removed.

How to remove only record 3 for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is when I do EntityManager.remove(), all records are removed and I want that only child(DiasTurma) is removed and not your parent(Turma)

That happens because you explicitely asked for the removal to be cascaded:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Since you specified `cascade = ALL`, every operation, including `remove()`, done on a DiasTurma, is cascaded to its parent Turma.